# C# and Office integration

Tags: c#, ms-office

I need advice on which path to take.

I'm developing a C# application and I'd like to have some integration with the Office suite.

The solution is going to be used for students / teachers in the final semesters of Law School, that serve low income families - our customers.

Almost all the interaction between our department and our customers are done by our interns - the Law School students.

### How it currently works

1. Our receptionist adds the customer's basic data to the system and schedules a visit.
2. Before the visit, our intern queries the internal system to see the customer data. The data may include records from previous visits.
3. The student meets the customer, trying to gather all the information needed to solve the customers' needs.
4. The intern then has to report the interaction with the customer to the supervisor - the teacher. To do that, the intern opens up Word and types some basic info (like its name and its teacher) along with info about the interaction.
5. The intern prints the report and takes it to be approved by his teacher.
6. Here, the teacher makes notes/evaluates the printed report, and three things can happen:
   6.1 - the report is correct and has all the info needed:  the teacher approves it as it is;
   6.2 - the report is somewhat incorrect: the teacher tells the student what to change and the next version is implicitly approved;
   6.3 - the report is incorrect: the teacher tells  the students what needs to be changed, and the next version needs to be explicitly approved.  He makes the changes and goes back to step 5.
7. When the report is approved, the intern copies the text from the Office document and pastes/add it to our internal Access system.
8. The teacher physically store all the reports' versions. These reports are used to later evaluate the students.

### Problems

Sometimes, after having the report approved, the student does not add the approved report to our internal system. All the interaction with the client is basically lost.

The other one is the extreme use of paper. Every reported is printed. Usually more than twice.

### My proposed solution

We use Office 2010 internally.

From our internal system, when seeing the customer's history, there'd a button that would launch Word, side by side with the internal application.

This Word would have "Save / Save As" buttons remove. Along with lots of controls that the user wouldn't need.

This Word instance would have a custom "Save" button that saves the report in a specific network area and sends it back to our system, closing that Word instance.

This report would show up to the teacher in "unapproved report queue". The teacher then opens the report and analyzes it. Again, a custom Word instance should show, with Word's revision control enabled. The teacher would make the changes and save it back to our system with one of three status (approved; automatically approve next version; reevaluate next version).

Optionally, the teacher could then evaluate the report right there. I imagine something like a custom ribbon, where he would enter the appropriate values (things like attention to detail, proper spelling, proper forwarding, etc). Both the evaluation and the version would be send back to the system and the student would see that.

Once again, the student will see on his part of the system that the report was evaluated and could see the teacher's notes, corrections and evaluation in order to prepare his next version.

### Shoot me down

OK... Am I flying too high here? Or is it doable? Can you tell me what path would you take?

Do you imagine it's simple? Or hard? How many hours you guys think that would take?

I need the solutions to be free. I don't have VS Professional, nor the approval to use paid Frameworks / tools.

I was thinking of using NetOffice (http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) to do that. Or do you reckon it would be easier to use VBA?

Am I making too many questions?

Comment: What developing experience do you have?  Are you stronger in C#/VB dot net or VBA? Have you looked into forms for the info processing?

Comment: I graduate in Computer Science 10 years ago, but I was mostly doing network related stuff. Recently I went back to developing. I'm doing some C# related stuff. Nothing big. 

I'm more comfortable/stronger with C#. But I'm willing to learn. 

And I'm not exactly sure about what you mean with "forms for the info processing". You mean the layout of the controls, etc? If so, no.

Comment: forms: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx. I haven't used it, but that NetOffice looks promising - and easier than interop. It's definitely doable, and I think the express versions of VS should fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have 2 options when dealing with Office in C#:

1. If the office files are from Office 2007 and earlier, you can read and manipulate the "docx" directly in C# using the free [OpenXML Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) from Microsoft. But only use this if you're confident you can create the solution entirely in C# as it won't actually open a Word window.
2. You can also automate Word from C# by using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx). Using InterOp, you can manipulate any file that is supported by Word itself. I believe you can also manipulate Word itself (send save commands etc) using InterOp.

I strongly suggest the use of OpenXML since InterOp is a bit bothersome to use and debug.